# Looping through groovy object(List) using each{it} and pass the the elements into a json payload in Jenkins

Tags: json, jenkins, grails, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have a list containing the name of workspaces in groovy Jenkinsfile. I wrote an each() loop to iterate through the list and use the names in the endpoint below to get the workspace ID from the api response.

```
def getWorkspaceId() {
def result = []
Listworkspace.each{
    def response = httpRequest(
        customHeaders: [
                [ name: "Authorization", value: "Bearer " + env.BEARER_TOKEN ], 
                [ name: "Content-Type", value: "application/vnd.api+json" ]
            ],
        url: "https://app.terraform.io/api/v2/organizations/${TF_ORGNAME}/workspaces/$it
    )
    
    def data = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response.content)
    println ("Workspace Id: " + data.data.id)
    result << data.data.id
}
   return result
}
```

After getting the IDs, I want to pass them as part of a json payload.

```
def buildPayload() {
    def workspaceID = new JsonSlurper().parseText(getWorkspaceId())
    workspaceID.each{

    def payload = """
{
    "data": {
        "attributes": {
            "is-destroy":false,
            "message": 
        },
        "type":"runs",
        "relationships": {
            "workspace": {
                "data": [
                    {"id": "$it", "type": "workspaces"}
                 ]   
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
    """
    return payload
}
```

Is there a way I can iterate through the list of IDs returned and append each json object for the key "data" after iteration. See the code below

```
"relationships": {
    "workspace": {
        "data": [
            {"id": "id1", "type": "workspaces"},
            {"id": "id2", "type": "workspaces"},
            {"id": "id3", "type": "workspaces"}
        ]
```

When making the api call, it throws a `400 Bad request error`.  I tried to print the payload and I found out it attaches the whole list of IDs to the payload.
Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
def buildPayload() {
    def workspaceID = new JsonSlurper().parseText(getWorkspaceId())
    workspaceID.each{

    def payload = """
{
    "data": {
        "attributes": {
            "is-destroy":false,
            "message": 
        },
        "type":"runs",
        "relationships": {
            "workspace": {
                "data": [
                    [id1, id2, id3]
                 ]   
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
    """
    return payload
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the JsonOutput class to make your life easier. In essence, as long as your `getWorkspaceId()` method  is returning a list of ids, you can do something like this:

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

def buildPayload(def ids) {
  def payload = [
    data: [
      attributes: [
        "is-destroy": false,
        "message" : "",
      ],
      type: "runs",
      relationships: [
        workspace: [
          data: ids.collect {
            return [id: it, type: "workspaces"]
          }  
        ]  
      ]
    ]  
  ]
  
  return JsonOutput.toJson(payload)
}
```

This will take each id in your ids list and build a map where each id is identified by its number and the type: workspaces key pair. This is all then included in the larger payload.